# Python Recursion def inside class, error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'rec'

Tags: python, class, recursion

I test the recursing on **VS CODE**

```
class Solution(object):
    def rec(self, x):
        print(x)
        if (x==25): return True
        return self.rec(x+1)

print(Solution.rec({},1))
```

and got an error:

```
PS D:\python leetcode> py re.py
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python leetcode\re.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(Solution.rec({},1))
  File "D:\python leetcode\re.py", line 5, in rec
    return self.rec(x+1)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'rec'
```

**However**
If I use

```
class Solution(object):
    def rec(self, x):
        print(x)
        if (x==25): return True
        return Solution.rec({},x+1)

print(Solution.rec({},1))
```

as using **Solution.rec** instead, it works.
**But in leetcode website**, using the 1st code `self.rec()` works, the `Solution.rec` does not.
I'm new to python, can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

`rec()` is an instance method, so you have to create an instance of the class and call the method on that.

```
print(Solution().rec(1))
```

You don't pass the `self` argument explicitly, it's automatically set to the object that the method was called on.

Comment: Note that in OP's second code snippet you will *also* need to make the change `return self.rec(x+1)` for it to work.

Comment: No, that's not necessary. `self.rec(x+1)` correctly passes `self` as the implicit first argument.